# Ruby: How to call a method with a proc instead of a block

Tags: ruby

I have a method that requires a block, but I just have a `Proc` object. How can I call it without ugly wrapping?

```
def twice
  yield
  yield
end

p = Proc.new { puts "Hello" }

twice p          # Does not compile "wrong number of parameters"
twice { p.call } # Ugly and difficult for additional parameters
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the `proc` to a `block` using unary ampersand (`&`):

```
twice &p
# Hello
# Hello
#=> nil
```